# How to enable all the modules installed on Magento using php

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I was trying to disabling some modules not in used and somehow my admin crashed and now I don't see any option to bring all the modules output back. Is there any way to get all the modules enabled again via any php script

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you disabled modules by the admin configuration page then a change needs to be made in the database. Enter this command by using phpMyAdmin or any other SQL tool you prefer:

```sql
UPDATE `core_config_data`
  SET `value` = '0'
  WHERE `path` LIKE 'advanced/modules_disable_output/%';
```

Comment: This helped me out so much. Thank you. Is there a way to disable all modules except the Mage Core modules needed? @clockworkgeek

Comment: @thismethod you could set the value of all `advanced/modules_disable_output/%` to 1, then set the value of `advanced/modules_disable_output/Mage_%` back to 0.  That disables everything then re-enables core modules.

Comment: @thismethod alternatively there is an option for `disable_local_modules` in the file `app/etc/local.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a command line way of doing this:

First you go into the folder where your magento is installed:

```
cd /public_html (or whichever folder it is)
```

Grant the 'mage' user some basic rights:

```
chmod 530 mage
```

Now your could install using this user:

```
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community name_of_module
```

When you copy the name of the module from the magento web site it will be :

`http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/name_of_module` 
make sure to replace the last forward slash with a space

```
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community name_of_module
```